# shuftipro_sdk: ^1.2.2 git not working for me https://pub.dev/packages/shuftipro_sdk

Tags: flutter, sdk, payment-processing, flutter-packages

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.shuftipro:ShuftiPro_SDK:0.2.6.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/shuftipro/ShuftiPro_SDK/0.2.6/ShuftiPro_SDK-0.2.6.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/shuftipro/ShuftiPro_SDK/0.2.6/ShuftiPro_SDK-0.2.6.pom
> - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/shuftipro/ShuftiPro_SDK/0.2.6/ShuftiPro_SDK-0.2.6.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/shuftipro/ShuftiPro_SDK/0.2.6/ShuftiPro_SDK-0.2.6.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/Toshiba/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/shuftipro_sdk-1.2.2/android/libs/ShuftiPro_SDK-0.2.6.jar
> - file:/C:/Users/Toshiba/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/shuftipro_sdk-1.2.2/android/libs/ShuftiPro_SDK.jar
> Required by:
> project :app > project :shuftipro_sdk

I want to implement shuftipro so I am using shuftipro_sdk: ^1.2.2 but it's though above issue in that git project, so any one help me to fix this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/shuftipro/Flutter-SDK they have a project in this git link